# Digest not generated after compiling assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

After executing `rake assets:precompile` in production environment it show a message saying

> Generated non-digest assets in 485ms

I also tried `rake assets:precompile:all`, `rake assets:precompile:primary` but still it isn't generating digest for assets. Here's my production.rb file.

```
Gullak2::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

  # Code is not reloaded between requests
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
  config.serve_static_assets = false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.compress = true

  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = true

  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.assets.logger = Logger.new($stdout)
  # Defaults to nil and saved in location specified by config.assets.prefix
  # config.assets.manifest = YOUR_PATH

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files
   config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # See everything in the log (default is :info)
  # config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

  # Precompile additional assets (application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS are already added)
  config.assets.precompile += %w( merchant.css merchant.js)
  config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
  # Disable delivery errors, bad email addresses will be ignored
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable threaded mode
  # config.threadsafe!

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found)
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
end
```

Comment: In what environment are you trying to compile digested assets?

Comment: I tried it for both development and production. It shows the same message.

Comment: And you've confirmed the files do not have a digest in the public/ folder after compiling?

Comment: have you tried to specify a compressor? like
`config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  config.assets.css_compressor = :sass`
obviously using the right gems for it?
and why are you using `config.assets.compile=true` if you are pre-compiling them? sure aren't you messing with environments? compiling is for development, precompile is for production.

Comment: Are you sure you're actually in production mode when precompiling? The safest bash command is `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`.  Also `assets.compile` should be false if you are precompiling as others have said, though this probably isn't causing the digest to be skipped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my fault. I didn't look through the log generated by `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` command. It generates assets twice. First it generates assets with digest and after that it generates the non-digested assets.

I was reading only the last message which said `Generated non-digest assets`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code out :-

```
task non_digested: :environment do
  assets = Dir.glob(File.join(Rails.root, 'public/assets/**/*'))
  regex = /(-{1}[a-z0-9]{32}*\.{1}){1}/
  assets.each do |file|
    next if File.directory?(file) || file !~ regex

    source = file.split('/')
    source.push(source.pop.gsub(regex, '.'))

    non_digested = File.join(source)
    FileUtils.cp(file, non_digested)
  end
end
```